# Object Detection through webcam for the blind

Tags: image, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am currently working on a toy that helps a blind kid to learn alphabets. 
I want to play a sound file as soon as the webcam detects the toy. 
I have explored SURF detection but the frame rate is too slow. And as i add on the reference images and sound files(since i have 26 alphabets and 26 corresponding sound files), the frame rate becomes very very slow.
I have tried out HAAR Classifier, modified it to detect the 26 toys but i cannot find a way to play the corresponding sound files.
I would be grateful if someone could guide me or suggest a way around it. 
I am using visual studio 2012. 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried other detectors? like orb or fast? there is a python sample @ plane_tracker.py.

Comment: So the question is: I can detect an object using a HAAR classifier, but how do I play a sound file? That would depend upon a lot of things that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @B.. -I can detect an object using HAAR classifier but there are 26 different objects with 26 different sounds for each. Is there a way to play the corresponding sound when that particular object is detected. For example- I have made the HAAR classifier for an apple , orange and banana and have to play Apple when apple is detected, Orange when orange is detected and so on so forth.

Comment: @ZawLin I have not tried FAST and ORB. I tried using SIFT but the frame rate was much slower. I will try using ORB and FAST and let you know if it helped.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov - Thanks for your link but i need to detect the object first and then play a sound. Playing the sound is not an issue but detection of the object is.

Comment: @Deb So "Playing the sound is not an issue" , and you "can detect an object using HAAR classifier" but "cannot find a way to play the corresponding sound files". Perhaps you need to rethink your question.

Comment: @B.. I have 3 objects Apple Orange and a Banana. I have the positive images for all of them. Now when i start my video capture the objects are detected. But i cannot find a way to find out which object is detected? Is it an apple or an orange or a banana.